# How to trigger S3 static website deploy using lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I hope you are doing well

I am working currently on this personal project to increase my knowledge on AWS infrastructure.

I have this API which deals with CRUD operations on a DynamoDB table, and want to have a static website hosted on S3 which consumes the data from the API. In order to create pages dinamically for some of the data from the APÌ, everytime that I add or delete an item from the table, it is necessary to build the website again in order for it to create pages for the new items added to the table or delete pages for items that were deleted from the table.

So I want to know how can I use a lambda function to trigger a static website that is hosted on S3 to re-deploy or re-build, so everytime that I change something on the DynamoDB table,  I can call this lambda function to re-build the S3 hosted static website. I know that I can use DynamoDb actions as trigger for lambda functions but I want to know how can I have a lambda to perform this re-deploy or re-building of the static web site.

Thank you for your attention, I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to do it with a lambda function.

You can achieve this by integrating [DynamoDB Streams and lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)([broader doc with examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html)). From there it would really depend on how your static site is structured, whether you use version control, etc. You could certainly write a lambda that's doing all the things (intercepting the event, creating the pages, send them to s3, etc).

But IMHO, CodeBuild would make it a little bit easier especially if your static site is version controlled in a repo, just because you can easily integrate it with nearly all major git repo providers (Gitlab, Bitbucket, CodeCommit). This way you could potentially use the lambda once triggered by the Dynamo event to just start the CodeBuild project which will make the redeploy.

Another option would be to intercept the Dynamo put/delete events (through CloudTrail) with Amazon [EventBridge and have a CodeBuild as a target directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eventbridge-tutorial-codebuild.html).